# React Native: Update navigatiorBar by Scene

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to update my `navigationBar`by parameters passed by my scene? I mean, I want to pass the params such as name, back and next buttons text in my scene and not by the way I found:

`this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'Second',
            component: Second
        });`

I want to pass to my navbar params such as title and etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `routeMapper` prop on `Navigator.NavigationBar` to do this.  The `routeMapper` is an object that defines three functions: `LeftButton`, `Title`, and `RightButton`, which the navigation bar uses to determine what it should render. Each of these functions receives four arguments:

- the route object
- the navigator component
- the index of the route object in the current route stack
- the current `navState` of the navigator component

So for example, if you wanted to create a navigation bar where you can customize the left and right button text, and the title, you could do something like this:

```js
const NavigationBarRouteMapper = {

  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.leftButtonText && route.leftButtonHandler) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={route.leftButtonHandler}
        >
          <Text>{route.leftButtonText}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return null;
  },

  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.rightButtonText && route.rightButtonHandler) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={route.rightButtonHandler}
        >
          <Text>{route.rightButtonText}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return null;
  },

  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.title) {
      return (
        <Text>
          {route.title}
        </Text>
      );
    }
    return null;
  },
};
```

When you create your navigation bar you can pass this object in the `routeMapper` prop:

```
<Navigator.NavigationBar
  routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
/>
```

And then you can render a new title, for instance, by passing your `route` a `title` property:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  id: 'your-route-id',
  title: 'Custom Title',
});
```

Your navigation bar will receive this `route` object that you're pushing in the `routeMapper` object, as shown above.

Comment: I already know this. What I'm asking if is possible to pass a param like title from my scene.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I misunderstood you.  I suppose you might do it by keeping a reference to your Navigator (`this.props.navigator.props.navigationBar`).  But that's a very un-React kind of thing to do, in my opinion, because the navigation bar is actually owned by the Navigator and not by the scene.  You would end up modifying the child of another component, which is fragile, I think.

Comment: This question of ownership has actually been brought up on the RN project before, e.g. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2615